# Resolve URL injection

Tags: php

I have a site where Google Security Issues say "URL Injection"

It added gibberish code at the end like:

```
index.php/tmo7kx9vo-5399_n0m43kqjv-4143-umoyzxfgs_cwbl_0exy6kre
```

I'm not sure how to resolve it as the index.php page doesn't contain a form of any type and checking and rechecking the code, I didn't find any malicious code.

Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: We can't help you. You are asking something but didn't share details to allow us to understand your problem. Please, read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you needing the site URL?

Comment: We need to see an example, a piece of code, something related with the issue. URL injection is a problem, but can be caused by tons of reasons. We can't imagine without an example.